# Lucene: What is the correct way to cancel a search?

Tags: java, lucene

I am currently looking into lucene and wondered what is the best way to cancel a search that is performed with the `org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher`?

I can imagine to simply call interrupt on the thread that i created for the search, but i'm not sure if the relevant components inside lucene react on interruption (without searching thru the depths of the source code).

Is there an 'official' way / what would be the best way?

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IndexSearcher` provides a constructor with an `ExecutorService` (follow the link in constructor for an example usage) as parameter. This can be used to terminate the search. However, note the remark on the use of `NIOFSDirectory`.

See https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html

And
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-2239

**Extract from the JavaDocs and issue ticket:**
It's important to not call `shutdownNow()` (interrupt the threads) when the default channel-based `FSDirectory` implementations are used. The use of the (slower) `RAFDirectory` seems to have no problem with the resulting interrupted threads.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
So if I understand the java docs and issue tickets correctly it's important to not call `shutdownNow()` when the default channel-based `FSDirectory` implementations are used. The use of the (slower) `RAFDirectory` seems to have no problem with interrupted threads.

Comment: That is also my understanding.

Comment: The note only takes about `NIOFSDirectory`, not `FSDirectory`.

Comment: And in the ticket it is said that "All AbstractInterruptibleChannel subclasses are affected" with `MMapDirectory` as another example.